# I'm not understanding why underscore gets grounded in meta-predicates

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using SWI-PROLOG.

Given a list where almost all elements are compound terms like:

```
 ?- MyList = [json([a=1, b=2]), json([a=4, b=1]), 999, json([a=7, b=2])].
```

I want to filter only the compound term elements, so i tried the following:

```
?- MyList= ..., include(=(json(_)), MyList, FilteredElems). 
FilteredElems = [json([a=1, b=2])].
```

i was hoping to get the following result `FilteredElems= [json([a=1, b=2]), json([a=4, b=1]), json([a=7, b=2])]` but only the first one is included.

I discovered that after the first call of the predicate, the underscore gets grounded to: `[a=1, b=2]` value, so the next attempts of succeding the unification with `json(_)` fail.

Does exists a clean way to solve this? Am i missing something?

To test the grounding of the underscore i used my modified include version:

```
inc(Goal, List, Included) :-
    inc_(List, Goal, Included).

inc_([], _, []).
inc_([X1|Xs1], P, Included) :-
      (   
          writef("Calling call(%t, %t)\n", [P, X1]),
          call(P, X1)
      ->  Included = [X1|Included1], 
          writef("\tTrue\n")
      ;   Included = Included1,
          writef("\tFalse\n")
      ),
      inc_(Xs1, P, Included1).
```

---

### Heading

I tried with predicate functor/3 and lambda (library yall); in this case the underscore get bounded to different values (in the below examples becomes 1; 1; _ ; 1; 2)

```
?-  MyList = [json(a), json(b), 999, json(c), json(d, 123)], include([E]>>(functor(E,json, A), writef("Arity: %t \n",[A])), MyList, FilteredElems).
Arity: 1
Arity: 1
Arity: 1
Arity: 2
FilteredElems = [json(a), json(b), json(c), json(d, 123)]. % As wanted
```

All is working as I expect in this case.

---

The same "problem" still happens when not using lambda; the underscore in this case get bounded after the first call.

```
test_functor_(FunctorName, Arity, Term):-
      writef("Term: %t, Arity: %t\n", [Term, Arity]),
      functor(Term, FunctorName, Arity).

?- MyList = [json(a), json(b), 999, json(c), json(d, 123)], include(test_functor_(json, _), MyList, FilteredElems).
Term: json(a), Arity: _8794
Term: json(b), Arity: 1
Term: 999, Arity: 1
Term: json(c), Arity: 1
Term: json(d,123), Arity: 1
MyList = [json(a), json(b), 999, json(c), json(d, 123)],
FilteredElems = [json(a), json(b), json(c)]. % Missing the last element
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: Try `\+ \+ call(P, X1)` instead of `call(P, X1)`.

Comment: Did it work? The answer was likely generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar).

Comment: @PauloMoura It works but i don't really understand why.

Comment: @PeterMortensen "works" in the sense that i can obtain the wanted result, but i would like to understand why in some other cases underscore doesen't "get fixed"

Comment: The double negation allows you to check that your test is successful without binding any variables, which is what breaks applying the test to the next list element.

Comment: Use the de facto standard `format/2-3` predicates instead of the deprecated `writef/2` predicate.

Comment: @PeterMortensen in my (limited) experience with ChatGPT, the code was almost always broken (unlike the code in that answer), and English was always perfect (unlike "You can take a different method to resolving this problem", and there's more, too). so I kind of doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track!

However, you were not asking one question, but three: (1) Does there exist a clean way to solve this? (2) Am I missing something? (3) Can someone explain?

Let me try to answer them separately...

---

Regarding **(2) and (3)** let me point out that you are observing *the same effect* with

```
?- ..., include(=(json(_)), MyList, FilteredElems).
```

and

```
?- ..., include(test_functor_(json,_), MyList, FilteredElems).
```

In both cases, the anonymous variable stands for **one** (and only one) value.

For the first query it is `[a=1, b=2]`, for the second one `1`.

---

Regarding **(1)**: Yes, lambdas can help by providing "internal" variables, just as you observed.

Alternatively, you can use an auxiliary predicate like so:

```
is_json(X) :-
   functor(X,json,_).   % "_" will be a fresh variable ...
                        % ... everytime is_json is called!
```

Sample query:

```
?- include(is_json,[json(a),json(X),123,foo,foo(2),json(a,b),bar(f),baz(z)],Xs).
Xs = [json(a),json(X),json(a,b)].
```